# Not able to use rasa x with current version of rasa

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, rasa, rasa-x, rasa-sdk

Rasa forum says that rasa x 1.1 supports rasa 3.x, but when i try running rasa x on a model trained with rasa 3.1 it gives me error.

```
UserWarning: Your version of rasa '3.1.0' is currently not supported by Rasa X. Running `rasa x` CLI command with rasa version higher or equal to 3.0.0 will result in errors.
```

and

```
The model was trained with Rasa version 3.1.0 but the current Rasa requires a minimum version of None. Please retrain your model with a more recent Rasa version
```

This is the rasa version I am working with.
[image]

I even tried downgrading rasa to version 2.8.27 but the pip wheel has been running for hours without much progress.

I have also tried to set my rasa, rasa x and rasa-sdk version to the compatible versions given on rasa documentations but with no success.

Please can someone guide me on how to get rasa x 1.1 running with rasa 3.1. And if it is not possible for rasa 3.1 with rasa x, can someone help me pin point the stable version for rasa and rasa x which will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the [Compatibility Matrix](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/changelog/compatibility-matrix/). This will help you to choose the compatible Rasa Open Source and Rasa SDK versions. However, it seems the problem you are facing is a bug from Rasa. You can keep an eye on [this thread](https://forum.rasa.com/t/rasa-open-source-3-1-and-rasa-x-1-1-launched/52550/13?u=mhmohona) in Rasa forum for the update.

Lastly, I have worked on various Rasa's version and till now I found these versions are more stable.

```
rasa==2.8.21 
rasa-sdk==2.8.3 
rasa-x==0.39.3
```

Comment: I did check the compatibility matrix. But didn't work out. I ll try  these version and see.

Comment: got this error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rasa-x==0.39.3 (from versions: 0.0.0, 0.0.1, 0.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rasa-x==0.39.3, trying with rasa==0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use socketio webchat if you plan to use rasa 3.x Otherwise, you need to downgrade rasa version.

To use socketio webchat do the following:

1. Activate socketio in credentials.yml as following

   ```
   socketio:
     user_message_evt: user_uttered
     bot_message_evt: bot_uttered
     session_persistence: false
   ```
2. run rasa nlu using the following command
   rasa run --enable-api --cors="*"
3. Try to use the following simple webchat js from RASA

   ```
   <div id="rasa-chat-widget" data-websocket-url="http://localhost:5005/"></div>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/@rasahq/rasa-chat" type="application/javascript"></script>
   ```